# In WPF how can I control whether another button clicked

Tags: c#, wpf, button, mouseevent

I want to determine another button is clicked in WPF.
I wrote same code as below, when I clicked that button the animation works after that when I clicked same button the animation work like as else block. But I want to control if another button is clicked and than I want to work of the else block.

```
int i = 0;
private void btnDashboard_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // btnDashboard.Click += btnDashboard_Click;
    // Button btnSender = (Button)sender;
    if (i%2==0)
    {
        DoubleAnimation anim = new DoubleAnimation(250, 1470, new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(300)));
        btnDashboard.BeginAnimation(FrameworkElement.WidthProperty, anim);
        ((ApplicationShell)App.Current.MainWindow).ShowPages(new UCDashboardIndicatorView());
        i++;
    }
    else
    {
        DoubleAnimation anim = new DoubleAnimation(1470, 250, new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(300)));
        btnDashboard.BeginAnimation(FrameworkElement.WidthProperty, anim);
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
        i++;
    }

}
```

How can I control it?

Comment: It isn't clear, what's the problem. Just write another `Click` handler for the button you want to control, or re-phrase the question.

Comment: In my code, when I clicked same button the animation works. but  I want to control if another button is clicked and then the animation should change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to use same Click handler for two buttons, Try this:

```
private void btnDashboard_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   Button btnSender = sender as Button;
   if(btnSender.Name == "btn1")
    {
      //Code for Button1
    }
    else
    {
      //Code for Button2
    }
}
```

Also make sure each button has a Name property set in XAML so that you can access it in code behind.
in XAML:

```
<Grid>
   <Button Name="btn1" Click="btnDashboard_Click"/>
   <Button Name="btn2" Click="btnDashboard_Click"/>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply add your other `Button` as a **subscriber** to the event.

```
<Button Click="btnDashboard_Click" ... />
<Button Click="btnDashboard_Click" ... />
```

And in your event method, you can get hold of the button that was clicked:

```
Button btn = sender as Button;
```

Then, you can apply your animation to the desired button:

```
btn.BeginAnimation(FrameworkElement.WidthProperty, anim);
```

*Note: The above code references `btn`, which could be either one of the two buttons that was clicked*.

If you need to take this a step further by applying an animation based on a specific button that was clicked, you could give each button a `Name` and test `btn.Name` in an **if statement**.